# MVC4, determine and calling custom validator

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I need to validate my model in business layer. So I have a custom validator in my class:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ToolMetaData))]
public partial class Tool
{
   public string PartNumber { get; set; }
}
public class ToolMetaData
{
    [Required]
    [ValidPartNumber]
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
}
public class ValidPartNumberAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
       ....
    }
}
```

I need to determine, if a field of my class has ValidPartNumber validator defined and to call it.

For Required validator I'm using following:

```
Tool t = new Tool();
ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForProperty(null, 
                                                  t.GetType(), "PartNumber");
if (metadata.IsRequired)
{
  validate..
}
```

But how can I determine, if my field has ValidPartNumber validator defined and call if afterwards?

Do I need custom DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider and DataAnnotationsModelValidator?

Tnanks a lot,

Alex

Comment: Unclear what your trying to do. What is the purpose of `[ValidPartNumber]` ?

Comment: With [ValidPartNumber] i'm validating my field "public string PartNumber" from the model. That's working fine, when I post my View. But I'm creating my Model Tool from external source (in my case xml file) and I need to validate my model tool using validator [ValidPartNumber] that is defined in metadata

Comment: Still not clear what your tryng to do. Which metadata are you referring to? I cant see how `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` has anything to do with your issue. Just guessing, but if your wanting client side validation to look up an external source to check if the user has entered a valid part number, then use the `[Remote]` attribute